# NiFi ExecuteScript with Groovy: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: groovy, classpath, apache-nifi

I'm trying to execute a Groovy script which is using Microsoft SQL server JDBC driver. I'm trying to specify the path of the sql jdbc jar in the modules directory. However, my groovy script complains that the SQLServerDriver class is not found.

This is what the configuration looks like -
[image]

This is the error that I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.loadDriver(Sql.java:705)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:445)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:23)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:352)
```

When I print my java classpath in my groovy script I don't see the added module in the classpath either.

```
println "classPath:" + System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

[The added URL shows up in the classloader.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3WeM.jpg)

Comment: Think the jar has to be in the nifi lib folder on all the boxes. And nifi will probably need a restart. Jdbi jars have to be in the system classloader

Comment: Thanks Tim. This did work. However, I wanted to know if adding modules in the execuuteProcessor works or am I doing something wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

The module won't be in your java.class.path, instead it is added to the classloader. The JAR only needs to be in the system classloader (lib/ folder, e.g.) if you are using DriverManager versus getting an instance of your driver class directly via Class.forName().newInstance().

Perhaps try forward slashes in your path, and if that doesn't work, an experiment could be to try a relative path. If that works, there's a Windows path bug in the processor.

Finally, you could set up a DBCPConnectionPool controller service using the driver JAR and settings, and then access it from your script using the technique I outline in my blog: http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/04/sql-in-nifi-with-executescript.html. That way the controller service is reusable by other processors (if need be) and it takes all the guesswork out of setting up the driver, connection, etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I actually debugged the Nifi execute processor and verified that the jar file was found and added to the path. Please see the edited image above. I'll probably go down the route of creating a shared processor and using it within my script as you showed. Just wanted to quickly test this one before I do that. Thanks for the blog by the way - very informative.